# Automated parameter selection for a GARCH model, in a similar manner to the forecast package

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, model-selection, garch

I was wondering: is there are a package in R for automated [GARCH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_conditional_heteroskedasticity#GARCH) model selection?  I'm thinking of something like what the [forecast package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/forecast/index.html) does for [ARIMA models](http://rgm2.lab.nig.ac.jp/RGM2/func.php?rd_id=forecast%3aauto.arima).

If I implement this myself, would it be appropriate to just do a grid search over the possible parameters for the GARCH and ARIMA parts of the model (using the [rugarch package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rugarch/index.html)), and select the one with the lowest AIC (or BIC)?

Comment: Did you come up with anything interesting in the end?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My experience with equities suggested that if you are confined to garch(p,q), then garch(1,1) is what you will want.  Using a components model (Lee and Engle) is better -- it is sort of like a garch(2,2) but not quite the same.

When modeling multivariate garch (where there was a lot of choice in parameterization), it seemed to be that BIC was defnitely better than AIC.  BIC has a larger penalty and so suggests smaller models.  It looked like the penalty should be even bigger than in BIC -- that the BIC models were still too big.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I'm trying to estimate a model that has an ARIMA and a GARCH component, and I was already thinking of constraining the garch component to (1,1).

Comment: The garch estimation and the ARMA estimation are pretty much independent of each other -- the ARMA estimates you come up with are likely to be very similar whether you estimate with the returns or garch residuals.

Comment: So could I could use the arima parameters from `auto.arima` in the `forecast` package, and just add garch(1,1) errors using `rugarch`?  That would certainly make things simpler.

Comment: Simpler and very likely to be seriously close to what you would get doing it the "right" way.

Comment: @PatrickBurns, are you refering to Engle & Lee *"A permanent and transitory component model of stock return volatility"* University of California at San Diego, Economics Working Paper Series (1993)? I cannot find the paper itself, only references... Could you include a link?

Comment: @PatricBurns, regarding the interesting finding that *The garch estimation and the ARMA estimation are pretty much independent of each other*, I think this may happen if the fitted conditional standard deviations vary only little so that effectively they are close to constant; then ARIMA+GARCH effectively collapses to just the ARIMA part. Is that the case, or do you have another explanation?